# How to use a function from one xsl in another

Tags: xslt

I have two xsl files: "one.xsl" and "two.xsl"

one.xsl:

```
 <xsl:function name="x:trans" as="xs:string">
    <xsl:param name="str"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:variable name="res1" select="x:translate_string($str)"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="$res1"/> 
</xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want to use function "x:trans" in "one.xsl"

How do i reference the function to another file?

---

The problem is that when i try to call for this function this way:

```
< xsl:value-of select="x:trans('Hello World')"/>
```

I get the following error message from browser:

Reference to undeclared namespace prefix: 'x'

Comment: If you have imported or included "one.xsl", then you will also need to declare the "x" namespace in "two.xsl" if you want to use it.

Comment: Also, you mention that the message from the *browser*...custom **functions are an XSLT 2.0 feature**.  No browsers currently support XSLT 2.0.  If you want browsers to execute your XSLT, you will need an *XSLT 1.0* solution.

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a complete, step-by-step  explanation how to call an `xsl:function`.

Answer (score 9):

Apart from the correct replies that you need to `<xsl:include>` or `<xsl:import>` (I'd recommend the latter as the former can often result in duplication errors), **your other problem is the following**:

1. **A function name must belong to a namespace**.
2. **The namespace must be declared** (defined and bound to a prefix) in the same file in which the function is defined.
3. **Any call to the function has to prefix the name of the function and that prefix must be bound to the same namespace** to which the function name belongs

Here is a simple example:

**I. File `deleteA.xsl` defines the function `my:double`**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:my="my:my"
    >
 <xsl:function name="my:double" as="xs:double">
  <xsl:param name="pArg" as="xs:double"/>

  <xsl:sequence select="2*$pArg"/>
 </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**II. File `deleteB.xsl` imports file `deleteA.xsl` and uses the function `my:double` :**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:my="my:my">
    <xsl:import href="deleteA.xsl"/>

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:sequence select="my:double(.)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**III. The transformation contained in `deleteB.xsl` is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<t>1</t>
```

**and the correct result is produced**:

```
2
```

**Additional comment**: At present no browser supports XSLT 2.0 transformations -- `xsl:function` is only available in XSLT 2.0 +.

Answer (score 4):

You want to either do `<xsl:include />` or `<xsl:import />`. `<xsl:include />` is simpler (it just drags everything in) while `<xsl:import />` is more flexible (if there are templates colliding between the two, the over-ride of the called by the calling is better defined and generally sensible).

Edit for added info:

You need to make sure you call the templates in the imported stylesheet using the appopriate namespace. The easiest way is to make sure you have matching xmlns:foo declarations in the stylesheets, though you could call foo:template in one stylesheet as bar:template in the other if it had xmlns:bar instead.

Comment: +1 I generally prefer import over include, as it provides more flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

In two.xsl:

```
<xsl:include href="one.xsl" />
```

Also see the description of include in the [XSLT 2.0 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-include).